# Using a quick sort at certain index in 2D list

Tags: python, list, sorting, quicksort

I am trying to use a quick sort to sort through a list of lists at index [1]. This is for a school project so I have t use the quick sort algorithm. 
For example:

```
list = [[2, 5, 3],
        [2, 4, 9],
        [0, 9, 1],
        [1, 1, 1],
        [4, 7, 5]]
```

I want to be able to do this, sorting by index[1]:

```
quickSort(list)

output:

list = [[1, 1, 1],
        [2, 4, 9],
        [2, 5, 3],
        [4, 7, 5],
        [0, 9, 1]]
```

This is my quick sort code:

```
def quickSort(list):
    pivot = list[0][1]
    lesser = quickSort([x for x in list[0][1:] if x < pivot])
    greater = quickSort([x for x in list[0][1:] if x >= pivot])
    return lesser + [pivot] + greater
```

When I run it I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    quickSort(list)
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 3, in quickSort
    lesser = quickSort([x for x in list[0][1:] if x < pivot])
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 2, in quickSort
    pivot = list[0][1]
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

I'm not sure why I am getting that because list[0][1] = 5. I also tried this:

```
def quickSort(list):
    pivot = list[0][1]
    lesser = quickSort([x for x in list[0][1] if x < pivot])
    greater = quickSort([x for x in list[0][1] if x >= pivot])
    return lesser + [pivot] + greater
```

But I got the error: T

```
raceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#12>", line 1, in <module>
    quickSort(list)
  File "<pyshell#11>", line 3, in quickSort
    lesser = quickSort([x for x in list[0][1] if x < pivot])
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

So I'm not quite sure what I am doing wrong, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**
@sweeneyrod
So this is what I wrote according to your hints:

```
def quicksort(lis):
    if len(lis) <= 1:
        return lis
    else:
        pivot = lis[0][1]
        less = quicksort([i for i in lis[1:] if i[1] <= pivot])
        more = quicksort([i for i in lis[1:] if i[1] > pivot])
        return less + [pivot] + more
```

And then I ran it with the list above, but this is what I got:

```
[[1, 1, 1], 4, 5, [4, 7, 5], 9]
```

Am I not doing something correctly?

Comment: First, always post an entire traceback, not just a description of the error, so we know which line is failing.

Comment: Also, your algorithm is completely wrong in the first place. You're not sorting the members of `list`, you're sorting the members of `list[0]`. Which are obviously `int`s, not `list`s.

Comment: In your new version, your `pivot` is the 1th element of `lis[0]`, rather than `lis[0]` itself. So most of your element lists end up getting replaced by their 1st element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem is that you want to sort the members of `list`, but you're actually sorting the members of `list[0]`. Those members are ints, not lists, so you can't index them. And, more importantly, they're not what you want to sort in the first place.

So, let's first fix that:

```
def quickSort(list):
    pivot = list[0]
    lesser = quickSort([x for x in list[1:] if x[1] < pivot[1]])
    greater = quickSort([x for x in list[1:] if x[1] >= pivot[1]])
    return lesser + [pivot] + greater
```

Now your `TypeError` goes away, but you just get a new problem. At each step, you're cutting the list in half to divide your work. That means eventually you get down to a list of one element. Which means either `lesser` or `greater` will be empty. And what happens if you call `quickSort` with an empty list? It immediately tries to take `list[0][1]`, which is an obvious `IndexError`.

So, how *do* you sort an empty list? That's easy: it's already sorted. So:

```
def quickSort(list):
    if not list:
        return list
    pivot = list[0]
    lesser = quickSort([x for x in list[1:] if x[1] < pivot[1]])
    greater = quickSort([x for x in list[1:] if x[1] >= pivot[1]])
    return lesser + [pivot] + greater
```

Here's an example of it running:

```
list = [[2, 5, 3],
        [2, 4, 9],
        [0, 9, 1],
        [1, 1, 1],
        [4, 7, 5]]

print(quickSort(list))
```

The output is:

```
[[1, 1, 1], [2, 4, 9], [2, 5, 3], [4, 7, 5], [0, 9, 1]]
```

Comment: I get `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list` when running your code. I am trying to sort the element at index 1 of each list inside the main list.

Comment: @Pythonist: Then you're not running my code. See the edit, which shows it working (with either 2.7 or 3.4). If you copied and pasted wrong and don't understand what you did different and don't show me either the code or the traceback, I have no idea how I could debug that for you.

Comment: @Abarnet: I must have c/p wrong it works now!

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you need a base case (one where you don't make any calls to `quicksort`. In quicksort, this case is usually a list with one or zero elements in it.

Here is an implementation of quicksort for lists of integers:

```
def quicksort(lis):
    if len(lis) <= 1:
        return lis
    else:
        pivot = lis[0]
        less = quicksort([i for i in lis[1:] if i <= pivot])
        more = quicksort([i for i in lis[1:] if i > pivot])
        return less + [pivot] + more
```

As this is homework, I will leave converting this into a function operating on a list of lists as an exercise for now.

Hint - you need only need to change three parts:

```
pivot = lis[0]
if i <= pivot
if i > pivot
```

Comment: did you see my edit? Are you sure I only need to change those three things?

Comment: @Pythonist: You actually only need to change the second and third. You _can_ also change the first… but then you also need to change `less + [pivot] + more`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, then check to see what needs to change to get it to work:

```
def quick_sort(lis):
if len(lis) <= 1:
    return lis
else:
    pivot = lis[0][1]
    less = quicksort([i for i in lis[1:] if i[1] <= pivot])
    more = quicksort([i for i in lis[1:] if i[1] > pivot])
    return less + [pivot] + more
```